# R how to automate a filter for unknown variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe and a list. The list contains the data I need to filter in the dataframe. How can I automate the filtering process when I don't know the variables in the list?

some sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(sample(1:2,10,replace=T)),
                 V2 = c(sample(c("A","B","C"),10, replace=T)),
                 V3 = c(sample(100:104,10,replace=T)))
```

The list, `f_list`, is created in another part of the application and eventually passed on to the function that needs to do the filtering. For example, some times the list contains V1 and V3

```
f_list <- list()
f_list$V1 <- c("2")
f_list$V3 <- c("101","103","104")
```

Other times it contains V1 and V2

```
f_list <- list()
f_list$V1 <- c("1")
f_list$V2 <- c("A","B")
```

and so on... the real data has hundreds of variables. How can I automate the filtering process that would look something like this when the variables are known?

```
df %>% 
  filter(V1 %in% f_list$V1,
         V3 %in% f_list$V3)
```

How do I construct the loop?

**EDITED**
I edited the name of the object, from `ls` to `f_list` per @I_0's reminder that objects should not have names of existing functions.

Comment: something like this? `df %>% 
  filter(get(names(ls)[1]) %in% ls[[names(ls)[1]]],
         get(names(ls)[2]) %in% ls[[names(ls)[2]]])`

Comment: @Mohanasundaram thank you, not sure that would work, I know I need a loop of sorts because I don't know if I'm getting 1 or 100. But I just figured this would work:  `nms <- names(ls) for(var in nms) {df <- df %>%  filter(.data[[var]] %in% ls[[var]])}` Anyone has anything better?

Comment: @guasi I guess you found it then. shorter you won't get it in R.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim, got it. I guess I'll go with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `if_any` and `cur_column`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(
    (if_all(
      .cols = names(f_list),
      .fns  = ~ .x %in% f_list[[cur_column()]])
    )
  )

#  V1 V2  V3
#1  1  B 100
#2  1  A 101
#3  1  A 102
#4  1  A 103
```

Note for the time being the `()` around `if_all` due to [cur_column() requires extra parentheses to work inside if_any() and if_all()](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6194)

Answer (score 1):

one approach:

```
## example data:
filter_list <- list()
filter_list$V1 <- c("2") %>% as.numeric
filter_list$V3 <- c("101","103","104") %>% as.numeric
```

notes: 1. avoid naming an object (your list `ls`) like an existing function (`ls()` in base R), 2. remember to match the type (`numeric`, `character` etc.) of filter criteria and filter object.

code:

```
library(dplyr)

filter_list %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  left_join(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reminder about not naming objects with existing functions. This is a VERY nice solution, but I would have to check the types and set them the list gets built. There are hundreds of variables of different types, some are numeric, others are character, other are factors and right now I'm not checking.

Comment: A `left_join` would not work. For it to work it needs to be an `inner_join`, otherwise you introduce NAs